# DNN 9 modifying roles

Tags: dotnetnuke

Does anyone know how to change roles of Unverified users to Verified ones on DNN 9 all at once?

I have more than 900 unverified users and would like them to make verified ones all at once if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it would likely be something like  (sql to be executed)

```
insert into userroles
(userid, roleid, createdbyuserid,createdondate,lastmodifiedbyuserid,lastmodifiedondate, status)
select userid, 1234, 1,getdate(),1,getdate(),1 
from users 
where userid not in (Select userid from userroles where roleid=1234 and portalid=0)
```

You might also need to do the following to "authorize" the users.

```
update userportals
set authorised = 1
where authorised =0 
and portalid = 0
```

where 1234 (replaced twice above) is the roleid of your registered users role (select * From roles)

Assumes you're working with PortalID 0, if you have multiple portals, you'll want to join to userportals as well to only do this for users in the proper portal.

Backup your database first, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by using ForDNN's Users Export/Import Tool:  https://github.com/fordnn/usersexportimport

You can export all or a subgroup of users, i.e. the Unverified Users, to a csv file, open it in a spreadsheet, change the user roles, and re-import.  That should modify existing users.

Test it before using ...